# Switch Customer Community Member based license to Partner Daily Login License

Tags: community, licenses

Can existing Customer Comm. member based login users in Salesforce switched to Partner Daily Login License. We are using this for our B2B business. The idea is to reduce the licensing cost by avoiding to buy named licenses.

Comment: Yes it's possible technically, better you reach out Salesforce support. You can chat on salesforce website.

Comment: ok thanks Ayub. I may do that.

Answer (score 0):

The customer community (cc) license has two flavors.

CC, and CC+. Each can be purchased as Member, or Login based pricing options.

Partner licenses are more expensive than cc or cc+ licenses.
Perhaps moving the cc member licenses to login licenses is a better approach?

The CC+ is very similar to the partner license, and can be changed. However, the user needs to be deactivated, given a new profile, a new license type, and reactivated.

Comment: Thanks eyewell this is helpful. Because of the ways we are mergining 2 different orgs, it seems we will get a big chunk of partner logins, and therefore we were thinking of moving over and using those. Any overheads if we were to do such - one thing is that we will end up converting all accounts to Partner account, any other concerns

Comment: Partner user capabilities are a superset of all community user license types, so you should be good. One area to watch: user volume scaling: Partner and CC+ licenses have advanced sharing capabilities and role hierarchy, which means that you can add upwards of 300,000 of these to an org, and higher (upper limit not known). This is a lower number than is possible with regular customer community licenses, which scale to the 10M+ users in an org (and much higher), but don't have the advanced sharing capability, or reports and dashboards, and few other features.